# TSA asking to see cell phone

Tags: airport-security, cellphones, tsa, tsa-precheck

Traveling in the US.

My plane ticket showed `TSA precheck`, so I was able to keep shoes on.

I put everything in my book bag/ carryon, and ever the paranoid person, asked my wife to go first and grab my stuff.

Sure enough I was picked for a random search. Here’s the question - does TSA have the right to ask to see my phone?

He did, and I told him I checked it in my bag, no way to get it. He wasn’t happy with that answer, but after repeating “so you have no possessions on you?” twice and me answering “no”, he swabbed my hands and let me go.

If I did have my phone, what exactly would he have done? Asked me to turn it on? Start looking through it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you are randomly selected for additional screening (which is a core part of TSA PreCheck as well as TSA procedures in general), the additional screening applies to you and all of your possessions.

TSA knows that almost every passenger going through security has a cell phone, so when you didn't have one they queried that fact - if for no other reason than the fact that it was different to normal, which is one of the things they are trained to look for.

If you had shown them your phone, they would have likely, at most, swabbed it along with your hands.  They would only have asked you to turn it on if they had specific suspicions about it not being a legitimate phone.  Per TSA policy, they would NOT have looked through the contents of the phone.

In this particular case, you lied to the TSA official.  That single action could have resulted in a very different outcome if your lie had been detected.

Comment: @Heinzi because who on earth checks in their phone.

Comment: *Per TSA policy, they would NOT have looked through the contents of the phone* - as a side note, Borders and Customs officers can do that (https://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/usa-border-phones-search-1.4494371)

Comment: They really just want something electronic to swab for explosives, it doesn't even have to be a phone. I've had them swab a video game controller because it was sitting at the top of my purse. They just ask for your phone because it's an electronic item almost everyone has.

Comment: When did he lie to the TSA official?

Comment: As Barmar said, I'm pretty sure OP really checked his phone in.

Comment: "I put everything in my book bag/ carryon, and ever the paranoid person, asked my wife to go first and grab my stuff" - Being 'paranoid' and having someone else take your stuff through screening is a *major* red flag.

Comment: @Barmar He told them his phone was in his check-in bag, when it was actually in his carry-on that his wife had taken.

Comment: @Doc The OP didn't say anywhere that his phone was in the carry-on that his wife was carrying. I agree that was likely the case, but you can't just state that as fact.

Comment: @marcelm OK, so lets forget the phone.  He clearly had other possessions, and a carry-on bag, that his wife had taken - and he stated he had nothing.  That's a lie.

Comment: @Doc Fair point, I agree.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - paranoid that after my things go through, they are stolen while I am still in queue for the metal detector. Those things have to include my phone,keys, and wallet. When a close friend had his scanned items stolen, he had no choice but to turn around and go home. It wasn’t some anecdote, it was a friend. Strange that this aspect of security creates such a risk. When I don’t have a companion, I do pack every last item in my suitcase.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That's why I always opt out and hold onto my things until the TSA agent that's going to feel me up signals for me. Only then do I put them through. One time I had to call out "NOT YOUR LAPTOP!" in an authoritative voice at a thief who was trying to make off with my MacBook. He already had at least one other laptop under his arm.

Comment: @Doc I interpreted "no possessions on me" to mean in his hands or pockets, not the carry-on bags he put through the security scanner.

Comment: para2 - would carrying 2, 3, or more cellphones be a red flag to TSA like carrying no cellphone ?

Comment: Did his wife take the stuff through security, or go ahead with her stuff to catch/watch his when it came through?

Comment: Theft of belongings at TSA checkpoints is super easy and can be a big deal for the former owners, who are often powerless to stop the theft.  It's amazing how strongly they deny this sort of thing ever happens, but probably because nobody wants to admit the full consequences of the system that has been set up.

Comment: This does not seem the correct answer. It claims to know what would be the guard intention, but overlooks what could the guard legally do.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Having your partner collect the items on the other side is simply an anti-theft measure, my wife and I always do it that way if we are together (I don't send them until she's in a position to observe what comes out.)  However, his paranoia comment sounds like he knew something was coming--probably a SSSS on his boarding pass.